# Cannot use WHERE variable in where clause for Insert stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, insert

I'm constructing a stored procedure for Insert only. What rows I want to insert to my target table depend on a composite key of fields. I'm trying to construct it before and then use it in the WHERE-clause, but I get this error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'*

My `@WhereClause` is holding this value from the string split:
`[Column1] = S.[Column1] AND [Column2] = S.[Column2] AND [Column3] = S.[Column3]`

**This is my code**

```
AS

BEGIN

    SET XACT_ABORT ON

    DECLARE @compositeKey NVARCHAR(MAX) =   'Column1,Column2,Column3';
    DECLARE @WhereClause NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

    BEGIN TRY

        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        SELECT @WhereClause = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(Value) + ' = S.' + QUOTENAME(Value), ' AND ')
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@compositeKey, ',');
        PRINT @WhereClause;

        INSERT INTO [target].[targetTable]
        (
        Bunch of columns...
        )
        SELECT
        Bunch of columns...
        FROM [source].[sourceTable] AS S
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM [target].[targetTable]
            WHERE + @WhereClause
        );
      
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
   
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        IF @@trancount > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        DECLARE @msg nvarchar(2048) = error_message()  
        RAISERROR (@msg, 16, 1)
        RETURN 55555

    END CATCH

END
```

It works if I put the result from my stringsplit directly behind the Where, that's why I thought I would work with the variable.

Comment: The easiest way to debug dynamic SQL is to `PRINT`/`SELECT` the statement first. Then you can debug that SQL and solve the problem before propagating the solution to your SQL that generates the dynamic statement. Often you'll find that the problems are quite simple, such as a typographical error that is difficult to spot in the literal strings; for example a missing whitespace/linebreak, or leading/trailing delimiters. Taking the time to get the non-dynamic statement working first is really important, as if that doesn't work the dynamic one will have no chance of working correctly.

Comment: We can't run your SQL, we have no sample DDL or DML for your objects, therefore we have no idea what your dynamic statement looks like.

Comment: Side note, there's also likely little need for a `TRY...CATCH` here. Just use a transaction and enable `XACT_ABORT`. You should also really be using `THROW` if you do want to (re)throw errors; it has been around d since 2012. Then there's no need to explicitly `ROLLBACK` either.

Comment: Sorry @ThomA, added how the WhereClause executes. (If that was what you were asking?)

Comment: Didn't we tell you to abandon this generic wrapper idea last time around?

Comment: That's not a complete statement, @WilliamAndersson , and was not what I was asking, no. (I didn't actually *ask* anything.) If you're trying to run the statement `[Column1] = S.[Column1] AND [Column2] = S.[Column2] AND [Column3] = S.[Column3]` that's not going to generate the error you state. On it's own it would generate an error *"Incorrect syntax near '='."*. If it *were* part of a valid statement, that `WHERE` is either misleading (as it should just be `S.[Column1] IS NOT NULL AND S.[Column2] IS NOT NULL...`) or it's going to generate an ambiguous column error.

Comment: `WHERE + @WhereClause` this makes no sense in static sql world. If you're writing dynamic sql then the whole INSERT should be inside a string and then executed together with WHERE.

Comment: Ahh, now I remember their [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78081359/2029983) @siggemannen .They then posted about it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/290817/166388) too.

Comment: @siggemannen What I abandoned was dynamic SQL, I realized it was very difficult,  open to SQL injection (after reading on it) and not good for my case. I have restructured it, and I believed this would work better. Its not a generic wrapper, it has one use case only. Just trying to make the code more effective. I could of course hard code the values, but just wondered if there was a way around that.

Comment: But now I got my answer to that. Thank you!

Comment: This just screams of being an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). If you would just post some real details about what you are trying to solve I am confident that you will find an answer. Delimited strings is a huge red flag that something has gone very wrong in the design here.